# dynamics crm 2016 on-premise non-interactive not showing in Access mode

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

dynamics CRM 2016 on-premise non-interactive not showing in Access mode
[image: non-interactive not showing in Access mode]

Comment: Verify if you have already created 5 non-interactive accounts, else open a ticket with MS..

Comment: Checked no records found

Comment: Have you verified in different browser, login ??

Comment: Are you online or on premise?

Answer (score 0):

It's only availble online.

- Create an integration user
- Assign license for Dynamics 365
- Update integration user from Read-Write to Non-Interactive
- Take license away
- User remains